# Bash Programming

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I've been trying all the morning thinking how to do what I want to do but... I am starting to feel desperate!

I have an array of rows and columns in a .txt file. So I want to create a script that gives to me this information:

If I type it to the terminal (**script.sh 1 2 3**), it should give me columns 1 to 3 from the .txt file.

If I type it to the terminal (**script.sh**), it should give me column 5 to the last column.

If I type it to the terminal (**script.sh 1 2 3 -g insulin**), it should give me columns 1 to 3 of the rows that contain the word "insulin". The -g here means "gene", so the aim is to look for that gene.

I've written a code that gives me the columns I want or all the columns if I don't introduce any variable, but I can't go ahead with the -g and gene variables... Do you have any idea?

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(echo $@ | tr " " ",")"

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
awk '{for (x=5; x<=NF; x++) {printf "%s ", $x } printf "\n" }' affy.txt
else
cat affy.txt | cut -d" " -f$var
fi
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
columns=""
word="."
for arg; do
    if [[ $arg == "-g" ]]; then
        shift
        word=$1
    else
        columns+="$1,"
    fi
    shift
done
if [[ $columns ]]; then
    columns=${columns%,}
else
    columns="5-"
fi
grep $word affy.txt | cut -d " " -f "$columns"
```

Comment: nice use of `shift` to parse the args

Answer (score 0):

You want your awk script to know about the search string from `-g`.  To pass values into a script, I have had good success with the `-v` argument of `gawk`.  Once you have the argument of -g in your script in variable `lookfor` (e.g., using `getopt`), run:

```
 gawk -v searchtext="$lookfor" -- '$0 ~ searchtext { print $1, $2, $3 }'
```

The `-v` argument makes `searchtext` refer to `$lookfor`, i.e., the argument to `-g` in the bash script.  Then `$0 ~ searchtext` selects any line where the search text is anywhere on the line.  For matching lines, the first three fields are printed.